# Would adding noindex on index.html stop main domain from being indexed?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, noindex

For various reasons, I don't want my `domain.com/index.html` from being indexed because I have the same file with the same content but called `domain.com/home.html` instead.

Now I added the `noindex` meta tag in my `index.html` file so search engines would not index it. Although, I was wondering if by doing that i'm preventing my `domain.com` from being indexed. Since it's basically the same URL, typing both variants will get you to the same page.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely yes, if there is a file which powers both URLs they will both have the noindex tag in the source code

Simple way to find out is add the `noindex` tag, then go to your `htttp://domain.com/home.html` and view the source code and search for noindex. If you can see it in the source code of your homepage, so will search engines and the page will be noindexed in time.

Another way to use `noindex` is in HTTP responses using .htacces, rather than adding it to the file code. Add the code below to your htacess to noindex just `domain.com/index.html`

```
<Files index.html>
   Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
</Files>
```

Another way to  avoid duplicate pages is 301 redirect the duplicate URL. You can do this by adding the code below into the .htaccess file on your site:

```
# Needed before any rewriting
RewriteEngine On

### Place after 'RewriteEngine On' and before any CMS specific rewrite rules

## 301 Redirects
# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /domain.com/home? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Another option is use canonical tags.  Add the code below in the source code of the file the powers both URLs:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://domain.com/home.html " />
```

When search engines crawl `http://domain.com/index.html`, the tag tells them to count the URL as a single URLs, `http://domain.com/home.html`

And if for some reason you cannot do any of the above, you can block it in robots.txt, which might look something like this:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /index.html$
```

This will block search engines from crawling `http://domain.com/index.html`, it won’t necessarily remove the page from the search results pages, but it will most likely be added to the omitted results and won't cause issues with duplicate content. This is the least favoured option though.

Also I might add, that if you have duplicate issues with `http://domain.com/index.html` and `http://domain.com/home.html`, then either of these pages are most likely a duplicate of your root home page, `http://domain.com/`. If so, then follow the same steps above, but so that all duplicates resolve too `http://domain.com/`

Comment: Wow a very detailed answer. Thanks for taking the time to write this. I chose the option of canonical url for my problem. It seems like the simplest way. I was using 301 redirects before but it caused issues with my addon domains being redirected to my main domain so I needed another solution. Again, thanks for the help!